# CSS row class makes certain elements go out of frame, while they should be static and stuck to bottom of display

Tags: html, css

Currently my page looks like this. The bottom navigation bar gets pushed down to the point where I have to scroll after adding a row class to get the two elements next to each other.

[image]

Here you can see another page without the row element where the navigation links are perfectly stuck to the bottom of the display (Plants and Room navigation element are not supposed to be in the reminders tab (picture 1) so ignore this element from picture 2) This page is scrollable and keeps my navigation bar in the right position but the Elements are not outlined properly. All the green box displays should be above on enaother as well as the edit and remove buttons. I  tried to fix this with my row class which I used for picture 1, but this caused the problem in picture 1.

[image: Elements working on another page without the row element, scrollable]

Here you can see what I am trying to achieve in the reminders tab

[image: The design I am trying to achieve]

I was wondering what is wrong with my current css code that causes this bug when a row element is present in my html.

If you know a better way to display items next to each other that could prevent this behavior that would also be welcome.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }

  .CheckButton {
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .ReminderDescription {
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
```

The html code snippet which causes the problem

```
{% block content %}
  {% for reminderInstance in Reminders %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="CheckButton">
      <form action="{{ url_for('reminder', Plant_id = reminderInstance.Plant_id) }}">
        <button class="NewButton NewButton1"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ReminderDescription "> Give {{ reminderInstance.Plant_name }} water {{ reminderInstance.TimeSinceWaterNeeded }} days ago </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

For the case that the problem is elsewhere I will include the entire html page as well ass the navigation css code.
Reminders HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Reminders </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='src/nav.css') }}">
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='src/Collection.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="{{ url_for('collection') }}" class="nav__link">
            <span class="nav__text">Collection</span>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="nav__link">
            <span class="nav__text">Home</span>
          </a>
          <a href="{{ url_for('reminders') }}" class="nav__link nav__link--active">
            <span class="nav__text">Reminders</span>
          </a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>

{% block content %}
  {% for reminderInstance in Reminders %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="CheckButton ">
      <form action="{{ url_for('reminder', Plant_id = reminderInstance.Plant_id) }}">
        <button class="NewButton NewButton1"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ReminderDescription "> Give {{ reminderInstance.Plant_name }} water {{ reminderInstance.TimeSinceWaterNeeded }} days ago </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Nav CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 55px 0;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: #4ea662;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.nav__link {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__link:hover {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.nav__link--active {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: #468454;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the entire thing inside a div as seen below with a width of 90% fixed the entire issue:

```
.div-2 {
      margin: auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: 90%;
 }
```